# Condition to stop for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This little program doesn't outpu the expected result.
Take a look and see if you can help please!

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String numInput;

    // Declaring and initializing answer variable to an empty string.
    String answer = "";

    // Declaring and initializing the 2d array "number".
    String number[][] = {
            { "10", "20", "30" },
            { "15", "25", "35" }, };

    System.out.print("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + number[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print("\n\tEnter a Number : ");

            // Expected input 10 or 15
            numInput = input.nextLine();

            // number on first line, first column.
            if (numInput.equals(number[i][0])) {
                found = true;
                System.out.print("\n\tNumber " + numInput + " found");
                System.out.print(" on line " + i + " colum " + j); 
            } 

            if (!found) {
                    System.out.print("\n\tNumber not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is suposed to take the user's input and compare it to the data in the array (first column only). But it only does for only the first number in the fist column

Comment: you say it `doesn't output the expected result`. What is the expected result? What do you get?

Comment: if a number in the fist column is entered, it should display "Number found" and on which line and column it is. Else "Number not found". But it only does that for 10 not 15 (which is in the first column).

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you do input.nextLine for each number in your array.
You should populate numInput outside of those 2 loops.
Like so:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String numInput;

// Declaring and initializing answer variable to an empty string.

String answer = "";

// Declaring and initializing the 2d array "number".

String number[][] = {

        { "10", "20", "30" },

        { "15", "25", "35" }, };

System.out.print("\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        System.out.print("\t" + number[i][j] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
}

boolean found = false;
System.out.print("\n\tEnter a Number : ");
numInput = input.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {            

        // number on first line, first column.

        if (numInput.equals(number[i][0])) {

            found = true;

            System.out.print("\n\tNumber " + numInput + " found");

            System.out.print(" on line " + i + " colum " + j);


            } 

        if (!found) {

                System.out.print("\n\tNumber not found");

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I need it to stop displayin "Number Found" or "Number not found" multiple times.

Comment: To fix that you will also have to remove that if statement outside of those 2 loops, in this case after them.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the comments in the code make my point clear you iterate though the Array while checking on a static column index therefore running though the j-loop is useless not to mention you set the input each j-loop ==> you would check if (when i=0) input[0][0] is input 3 times with 3 different inputs

```
    boolean found = false;
    //Input needs to be moved here so you don't iterate though it for each column.
    System.out.print("\n\tEnter a Number : ");
    numInput = input.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            //for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {    You cant determine if you found it in the column J because your are checking for [i][0] therefore the for loop for J is useless as it would match regardless of what number j is
            // number on first line, first column.
            if (numInput.equals(number[i][0])) {
                found = true;
                System.out.print("\n\tNumber " + numInput + " found");
                System.out.print(" on line " + i + " colum 0");
            }
            if (!found) {

                System.out.print("\n\tNumber not found");

            }
        //}
    }
```